# How to stop Python program inside try block

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to do something like this:

```
try:
  if True:
    sys.exit()
exception:
  pass
```

But instead of stopping my python program, it is going to the exception block and the program is still running.

Here is my code but did not work:

```
close = None
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'I understand')]"))).click()
    close = True
except:
    pass

if close == True:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: try replacing sys.exit() with exit()

Comment: How do you find out that "it did not work"? What happens instead? Do you know how to use a debugger? Why set `close = None` and not `close=False`? You exit from within a try block by putting that code into the try block instead of after the try block.

Comment: In your current code, `sys` is not defined, you need to import it. I guess, you got a `NameError` indicating exactly that

Comment: Stop using `except` without an explicit exception. `except Exception` will not catch `SystemExit`, as `SystemExit` extends `BaseException` directly, not `Exception`.

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure why bare excepts are allowed. The need to catch `BaseException` is so rare that it seems silly to provide `except:` as a shortcut for `except BaseException`.)

Answer (score 0):

1. No need for `close` flag here As I mentioned below.
2. Don't forget to close the driver. Otherwise the process remains open.
3. Your except block is too broad.

With the code below if the element is found, it will close the driver and exit. Otherwise it will silent the `TimeoutException` exception and continue after the `else` block.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import sys

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'I understand')]"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
else:
    driver.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: that would interest me too ;D